# How to add a class to a dll without recompiling the dll?

Tags: class, external

How to add a class to a dll without recompiling the dll?

I have a library I'm using, and I don't have the source code.

I would like not to touch the library but be able to add new classes to the library.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new dll with whatever classes and functions you need, you can write them as extension methods and the will appear as if in the same namespace.
You will have to add an additional reference to this dll for all projects that use the existing library or use "ilmerge" to merge the dll's.